# Adding an error message to a custom validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, customvalidator, custom-errors

I have a custom validator and I am trying to output an error message when it fails but have been unable to do so. Could someone please tell me if I am doing this in the correct place.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "user"

  attr_accessible :name, :ip, :printer_port, :scanner_port

  validates :name,        :presence => true,
                          :length => { :maximum => 75 },
                          :uniqueness => true                          

  validates :ip,          :length => { :maximum => 75 },
                          :allow_nil => true     

  validates :printer_port, :presence => true, :if => :has_association? 

  validates :scanner_port, :presence => true, :if => :has_association?          

  def has_association?
    ip != nil
  end
end
```

I had it as follows:

```
validates :printer_port, :presence => true, :message => "can't be blank", :if => :has_wfm_association?
```

But was receiving an error

```
Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'
```

And when I tried to put the message at the end of the validator the comma seperating the has_association? turned the question mark and comma orange

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `message` and `if` parameters should be inside a hash for `presence`:

```
validates :printer_port, :presence => {:message => "can't be blank", :if => :has_wfm_association?}
```

This is because you can load multiple validations in a single line:

```
validates :foo, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

If you tried to add a message to that the way you did, or an `if` condition, Rails wouldn't know what validation to apply the message/conditional to. So instead, you need to set the message per-validation:

```
validates :foo, :presence => {:message => "must be present"},
                :uniqueness => {:message => "must be unique"}
```

Comment: Do I not need to include the true statement in presence? When I do this the ? and the end of the hash are running together and both turning orange.

Comment: Just needed to put the space, thanks for your help Dylan very much appreciated :)