# Customizing Model Validation error messages alerts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, locale, alert, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to customize the error message alert that users see at the **top of a form** when they input data incorrectly.  The error message alert I'm trying to customize are for Model Attributes which are in a nested form.

I've tried the solution [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) which says to edit the `config/locales/en.yml` file but this only changes the message not the name of the model & attribute which are displayed before the error message.

I've also tried what Billy's suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15696077/1814446) bellow which has the same result. i.e.

**1 error prohibited this hikingtrail from being saved:**
    **- Directions directions from 'My Custom Blank Error Message'**

Is there a way for me to display a more user friendly Model & attribute name in my error message or remove them entirely from the error message?

Here is what I have:

### config/locales/en.yml

```
    # Sample localization file for English. Add more files in this directory for other locales.
    # See https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails%2Flocale for starting points.
en:  
  activerecord:
    models: 
      direction: "In the Getting There section"
    attributes:
      direction:
        directions_from: "From field"
    errors:
      full_messages:
      format: "%{message}"
      models:
        direction:
          attributes:
            directions_from:
              blank: "My Custom Blank Error Message"
```

### Model

```
class Direction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hikingtrail

  attr_accessible :directions_by, :directions_desc, :directions_from

  validates :directions_from, :presence => {message: "'My Custom Error Message'", :if => Proc.new { |a| a.directions_by? || a.directions_desc? } }

  validates :directions_by, :presence => {message: "'My Custom Error Message'", :if => Proc.new { |a| a.directions_from? || a.directions_desc? } }

  validates :directions_desc, :presence => {message: "'My Custom Error Message'", :if => Proc.new { |a| a.directions_from? || a.directions_by? } }
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:message` option to assign custom error message.

Example:

```
validates :directions_from, presence: true, 
  message: "'Direction from' really really really can't be blank!"
```

Then this custom error message will appear as `<%= msg %>` in the form view.

Ref: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message

**Add**
To answer OP's question on the comment, i.e. the message shown in web page is not very friendly, showing result as "Directions directions from 'Direction from' really really really can't be blank"

The reason is the view template use `errors.full_messages` to show the error messages. You can easily customize it with two options:

Option 1: Write the custom message without subject. i.e. `really can't be blank`

Option 2: Write the message as before in full sentence, but refer to `message` only in view, instead of `full_message`

Example:

```
<% @hikingtrail.errors.messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

Ref: http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActiveModel/Errors (`full_message` is nothing more but a mix of `attribute` and `message`)

Comment: Thank you Billy, I tried this but it gave a similar result, it dispalyed the new message but after the model & attribute names which aren't user freindly i.e. **Directions directions from 'Direction from' really really really can't be blank**.  I've updated my question after trying this, do you know how I could remove the **Directions directions from** from the error message alert?

Comment: By the way for anyone following this question I had to amend Billy's code slightly as I had an `if` parameter in my validation. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10335836/1814446) for more detail

Comment: @rossmc, check my added answer.

Comment: Thanks again Billy I just option 2, it threw back the following error alert: **[:"directions.directions_from", ["'My Custom Error Message'"]]**.  I'm not sure why it added all the square brackets & quotations, could it be because these are nested attributes? I'll play around with the code some more.

Comment: @rossmc, I have not tested the code, just an idea. I checked again, using `each` along should be able to do the trick, just mention `errors_array` within the block. http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActiveModel/Errors:each

Comment: I tried that i.e.       `<% @hikingtrail.errors.messages.each do |msg, errors_array| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>` but I now get this error message alert **directions.directions_from**

Comment: No, it should be `<% @hikingtrail.errors.each do....`, without `messages`, look at the doc to see sample.

Comment: sorry, I'm not really getting this, in my form view I've tried       `<% @hikingtrail.errors.add(:directions_from, "can't be blank") %>
      <% @hikingtrail.errors.each do |attribute, errors_array| %>
        
      <% end %>` but It's not doing anything

Comment: I think I may skip the custom errors all together & just use `<%= pluralize(@hikingtrail.errors.count, "error") %> below.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27192/discussion-between-billy-chan-and-rossmc)

Comment: Thanks Billy, I used what you suggested in the chat, `<% @hikingtrail.errors.each do |attribute, errors_array| %>
<%= errors_array %> <% end %>`.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 6, it's now possible to customize the format used by `full_messages` helper at the model or at the attribute level.

```yaml
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        direction:
          attributes:
            directions_from:
              format: "%{message}"
              blank: "'Direction from' really really really can't be blank!"
```

This way the generated message for this error would be your message without the model prefix, leaving intact the default full_messages for other models and attributes.

More on that in this article :
https://blog.bigbinary.com/2019/04/22/rails-6-allows-to-override-the-activemodel-errors-full_message-format-at-the-model-level-and-at-the-attribute-level.html